# Building StreamExecutionEnvironment from a json

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

Is there a similar module to Storm's TopologyBuilder in Flink to build StreamExecutionEnvironment?

Basically, I want to configure my source and sinks in a JSON file and I would like to build the StreamExecutionEnvironment seamlessly from the JSON data without having to add code every time when I want to modify my DAG.

My JSON representation would be something like this

```
{
 [
  {
   "id" : "source",
   "subscriptions": ["intermediateSink", "destinationSink"]
  },
  {
   "id" : "intermediateSink",
   "subscriptions" : ["destinationSink"]
  },
  {
   "id" : "destinationSink",
   "subscriptions" : []
  }
 ]
}
```

I would like to know if Flink exposes a way to build the ExecutionEnvironment from a file like this.

I already have a Storm topology built using Storm's TopologyBuilder class. Something similar to [this](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder) but the Spouts and Bolts are created and linked based on my JSON instead of creating and linking them one by one.

I would like to do something similar for my Flink setup.

Comment: I don't know of any support in Flink for defining a workflow from JSON

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I didn't see anything provided by Flink, but I was able to write some custom code to build the ExecutionEnvironment from JSON, for our use case.